# Swap array elements depending on function (given as argument) return

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a problem with function that takes: array, size of that array and function (or lambda), and then sort given array depending of what function given in argument returns. For example:

int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

part(a1,6,isEven); // where isEven is simple function for checking if element is even

Should return:

[ 2 4 6 1 5 3 ]

I already write this like that, where im retur new, sorted array:

```
template <typename T, typename FUN>
size_t part(T* arr, size_t size, FUN f) {
    T new_arr[size] = {};
    int first = 0;
    int last = size - 1;
    int index = 0;
    bool changed = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(f(arr[i])){
            new_arr[first] = arr[i];
            first++;
        } else { 
            if(!changed){index = i;}
            new_arr[last] = arr[i];
            last--;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        std::cout << new_arr[j] << " ";
    }
    return new_arr;
}
```

But I have to do this without using any other array. And it has to be done in one loop.

Comment: Do you need to "sort" the array or "partition" it? "Sorting" would suggest that the input function might return integers, and the elements have to be arranged in increasing (or decreasing) order based on what the function returns. Your example looks more like a partition, where the function is known to return a boolean, and all the "true" values are before the "false" values (not necessarily caring how the elements are ordered within those two categories).

Comment: Your function is declared to return `size_t` but you return a `T*` - What's the thought there? Also `T new_arr[size]` is a VLA (variable length array). Those are not part of standard C++. You'd better learn to use `std::vector<T>` instead. While at it, you could take a `const std::vector<T>& arr` instead of a `T*` and a `size_t` as arguments to the function too.

Comment: Because this function has to do other things also. Just assume its VOID. @JaMiT - you are right. I mean partition, not sorting.

Comment: @Kamil Use two pointers one pointing at the first array element, one pointing at the last. Test the two values being pointed at. Depending on the result you may want to swap the two values. Then depending on the result you may be sure that the pointed at element is in the correct partition, if it is then increment the lower pointer, or decrement the higher pointer, or both. Repeat until both pointers meet in  the middle.

Comment: What is _"Because this function has to do other things also"_ an answer to?

Comment: @john can you explain in code how to achive that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo to declared size_t
This function has to do exactly what JaMiT said in first comment.

Comment: @Kamil Frankly no, I'm not in the business of writing the code for you. I'd hoped the explanation is clear enough to follow, and that you could write the code yourself. I'm also hoping it's correct.

Comment: @Kamil Nothing JaMiT said in the first comment explains your `size_t` as I can see. Have you tried `std::partition`?

Comment: @Kamil Take your example `{1,2,3,4,5,6};` Initially the two pointers are pointing at 1 and 6, Testing those two values 1 fails and 6 passes, so they need to be swapped `{6,2,3,4,5,1};`, now we can be sure that both 1 and 6 are in the correct partition, so the next two numbers to test are 2 and 5. And repeat. On each step there are only four cases to deal with, both numbers pass, both numbers fail, first fails and last passes, or first passes and last fails. It shouldn't be too hard to deal with all those possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do this with your help.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there.

You must not use an additional array. But in line `T new_arr[size] = {};` you try to do this. And, this will not work, because this is a VLA (Variable Lenth Array). VLAs are not part of the C++ language. Some compilers accept VLAs as extension, but, if you tell them to compile C++, then also those will reject it. In C++ the size of an array must be known at compile time. It must be a constant.

So, since you anyway work with pointers, you can also use `new` to allocate temporary memory. Then simply replace the above line with `T* new_arr = new T[size]{};`

And, you must not forget to delete the allocated memory. Or, you could copy the new data at the end of the function to the original and then delete the temporaray memory there.

So, in my opinion not the best approach. Anyway, the C++ standard library has the functions [partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) and [stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Anyway. Please see below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
template <typename T, typename FUN>
T* part(T* arr, size_t size, FUN f) {
    T* new_arr = new T[size]{};
    int first = 0;
    int last = size - 1;
    int index = 0;
    bool changed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (f(arr[i])) {
            new_arr[first] = arr[i];
            first++;
        }
        else {
            if (!changed) { index = i; }
            new_arr[last] = arr[i];
            last--;
        }
    }
    return new_arr;
}

int main() {
    int data[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    int *p = part(data, (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])), [](const int i) {return i % 2 == 0; });
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])); ++i) 
        std::cout << p[i] << ' ';
    delete[]p;
}
```